# Send JSON request - JQuery analog

Tags: android, json

I need to send a JSON request similar to jQuery's ajax method.

The official  [documentation](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-use-httpurlconnection-post-data-to-web-server/139) quote on the data parameter says:

> If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting

So I have the same situation - a key that maps to an array **"parameters":[123123, {"category":"123"}]**

The complete data parameter looks like

```
$.ajax({
     url: "/api/",
     data: {"parameters":[123123, {"category":"123"}], "anotherParameter":"anotherValue"}
```

Would you mind telling how to achieve the same functionality in Java ?

UPD:

I've made it to work with the use of gson + collections + post request.

Here're some guide lines:

- Sending [POST requests](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-use-httpurlconnection-post-data-to-web-server/139) in JAVA.
- You might also want to consider [performance issues](http://martinadamek.com/2011/02/04/json-parsers-performance-on-android-with-warmup-and-multiple-iterations/) related to different kinds of json parsers

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far and what exactly is the problem? Is it that you don't know how to create a connection, that you don't know how to serialize your objects or that you don't know how to make the thing run asynchronously?

I don't think Java has any asynchronous HTTP call methods, you need to use a regular URLConnection and run it in a separate thread. The connection itself is formed like this:

```
URL url = null;
URLConnection urlConnection = null;
String myURL = "http://example.com/ajax.php?foo=bar";
try {
    url = new URL(myURL);
    urlConnection = url.openConnection();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
InputStream responseStream = null;
try {
    responseStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return; 
}
```

Then you must use something like the [AsyncTask class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to make it a background job.

For converting your objects to JSON you might want to use the [GSON library](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

Comment: Basically, I need to send **{"parameters":[123123, {"category":"123"}], "anotherParameter":"anotherValue"}** regarding jquery doc. note mentioned  above.

Comment: in terms of composing URL - how would you make it? One of the parameters is an array, I suggest it should be at least a POST request